# Docker Windows container crashes with Azure Service Fabric

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, windows-container

I am trying to run a Docker image inside a Service Fabric cluster.
This image runs fine on my local machine. However, when I deploy it to either my local cluster or a cluster on Azure Service Fabric, it starts to crash.

I tried running the docker ps command on the machine. It shows a container image running, but after 5s when I run the command again, it shows an empty list.

My application is built using ASP.NET Core 2.0.7 and my container image is microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.7-nanoserver-1709

I am using the below OS for my cluster:

> Offer: WindowsServerSemiAnnual SKU:
>   Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk

I see the below error:

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting',
>   Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:EntryPoint'.
>  There was an error
>   during CodePackage activation.System.Fabric.FabricException
>   (-2147017731)
>  Failed to start Container.
>   ContainerName=sf-2-4e0c854d-d2d9-458a-82c5-78da874dc520_6fd774de-4796-4563-ab3f-c3bbb4d49e0c,
>   ApplicationId=ServiceFabricApplicationType_App2,
>   ApplicationName=fabric:/ServiceFabricApplication. DockerRequest
>   returned StatusCode=InternalServerError with
>   ResponseBody={"message":"container
>   fb204978704c52917704f1f6985ec9a73c9e76596e7258ff0ffce93c9c5109e0
>   encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows
>   system call

Comment: Do you get any error messages when starting the container? Try running with -it to get more info.

Comment: Yeah did try running container in interactive mode, I found that .net core dependencies were missing. So I added below tag <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest> with which container is running fine now. However when deployed on cluster using service fabric. It still fails.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you're running into this because of a mismatch between the version of Windows inside the image vs the version on the host.
Check out the compatibility list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility).
(It specifically mentions your error message.)

> To resolve this, you could:
>
> Rebuild the container based on the version of microsoft/nanoserver or microsoft/windowsservercore
>
> If the host is newer, use docker run
> --isolation=hyperv ... Run on a different host with the same Windows version